# Escaped characters in typewriter font

Tags: fonts, verbatim, characters, typewriter, font-encodings

I know a number of ways to fix this (e.g. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`), but I want to understand what's happening in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\$ \% \& \{ \} \_ \# \textbackslash \\
\ttfamily \$ \% \& \{ \} \_ \# \textbackslash \\
\verb+$ % & { } _ # \ +
\end{document}
```

[image: escaped characters]

- Why does attempting to obtain a `\ttfamily` brace, underscore or backslash result in the substitution of the ordinary roman symbol? The glyphs are clearly not missing, because verbatim mode can access them.
- How exactly is verbatim mode accessing these glyphs?
- Deleting the braces and the backslash, so that the underscore is the only remaining 'problem' character eliminates the font warnings, despite the fact that a substitution is still taking place. Why is this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\verb` and `verbatim` assume the font has these characters in their ascii positions and locally makes the characters be catcode 12 (like punctuation) with no special defintion.

`\textbackslash` (and friends) is defined to be a encoding-specific command and (to fake an air of sanity over the original TeX encodings) LaTeX assumes that `OT1` encoding is the encoding of `cmr10` which does not have a backslash char. So in `OT` the default definition is used (which uses the math fonts). `\ttfamily` changes the family but not the encoding and so in that case you get the OT1 definition even though the `cmtt` font is really encoded differently.

Things work better in `T1` because the fonts labelled as T1 encoded do in fact have the same encoding.

`\_` is different because `\textunderscore` has a default definition that doesn't use a font at all but a horizontal rule.