# How to escape curly braces within \texttt{}

Tags: braces, typewriter

How can I escape curly braces within the `\texttt{}` environment?

`\texttt{ \{ }` produces errors within my template, which can be found here: ([link](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/))

I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23473/how-to-escape-in-a-descriptions-item-tag) question for square braces, but the solution seems like a bit of a hack, and doesn't work for curly braces.

(FYI, the purpose of this is to include a regex statement in monospaced font, among normal font in the rest of a table. If there's a preferable solution, I'm open to ideas there.)

Comment: Something like `\texttt{This has \{brackets\} in it}`?

Comment: Nope. Apologies, should have added what I'd tried!

Comment: It's not too late to add a MWE :)

Comment: @Chris what you tried will work unless you are using 7bit OT1 encoded fonts which don't have `{` (except in typewriter) there is very little reason to ever be using those now. If you use T1 encoded fonts `\{` works as shown in Ian's answer

Comment: In your edit you say `\texttt{\{}` produces errors. That should not produce an error (but may use the wrong font if you use OT1) Please _always_ post a complete document that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Thank you David. I'm using a provided template ([link](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/thesis-template/)) - so it is likely I am using an outdated font. If I encounter further problems, I'll make that change, but for now, the quick-fix is working.

Comment: @Chris whatever font you are using, the input that you show should never generate an error

Comment: Apologies David - I've added a link to my template to the question, for future viewers. I didn't realise the problem would be specific to the template.

Comment: Related (different character, same mechanism) [characters - Underscores in words (text) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For "escaping" one typically use `\`, as in `\{` and `\}`. However, for the typewriter font, you might be interested in `\string{` and `\string}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Compare \texttt{\string{\string}} to \verb|{}| and \texttt{\{\}}
\end{document}
```

`\string` provides similar output to `\verb`, but is allowed in moving arguments.

Comment: Thank you - `\string{` is the one for me!

Answer (score 12):

Use a short verbatim environment, or load the `fontenc` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\{ Braces \}} \{ Braces \} \verb+ { Braces }+
\end{document}
```

[image: braces]

The braces in the middle version are 'ordinary' text; the ones you need are on the left
and the right. Without `fontenc`, the first method will give the wrong symbols. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68002/2417) explains what's going on.

Comment: This is good -- totally forgot about the ability to change the delimiter with `\verb`.

Comment: Thank you - both are valid options. In this situation, I'll use Werners `\string{` instead, as it appears `\verb` doesn't work within the `tabular` environment - and I presume I'm better to avoid loading a full package where possible. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: another technique that works is `\textt{\char \{}` (with a backtick between `\char` and the `\{`, which can't easily be shown here in comments) and similarly for the closing brace.  it's a plain tex/"old style" convention, but that's what i learned first and old habits die hard.

Comment: The stack-exchange comments are peculiar. I can surround the inline code with two backticks to include a single backtick in the code span: ``\textt{\char`\{}``, but I can't surround the inline code with three backticks to show how it was done.