# How to escape curly braces in \texttt inside math mode?

Tags: braces, typewriter

In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181118/how-to-escape-curly-braces-within-texttt) was answered how to escape curly braces within `\texttt{}`. On answer suggest using the `fontenc` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
  \(a + \underbrace{\mbox{\tt\{c\}}}_d\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another answer suggest using `\string{`. <del>However, in this case I got an error</del>. Sorry, I do not get why it was raising an error. Example bellow works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \(a + \underbrace{\mbox{\tt\string{c\string}}}_d\)
\end{document}
```

I now that in this case `fontenc` solves the problem. Thus, my question is how can I this without using `fontenc`. I do not see problems with `fontenc` is only curiosity.

Comment: What do you want to do? In a normal document, there is no error with your code and I don't need `fontenc` for it. Do you want to write it to some file?

Comment: what output do you expect from this? It is hard to guess. given `\texttt\string` the argument to `\texttt` is `\string` which will then generate an error. You don't need `\mbox` around `\texttt` so what do you want that is different to `\underbrace{\texttt{\{c\}}}}`

Comment: I added the example that produces the error. I want to get the same result that I get with the code above with `fontenc` but without using it.

Comment: No, your examples can not be run on their own, if you want to demonstrate an error please make a complete document that makes the error, the code I posted in the previous comment should not generate an error

Comment: Thanks all. I see that my question was not clear enough. So, I will improve the question description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `\{` and `\}` is that, if the current font encoding is OT1, the braces will be taken from the symbol font.

You have two strategies:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\underbrace{\texttt{\string{c\string}}}$

\end{document}
```

or the simpler

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

$\underbrace{\texttt{\{c\}}}$

\end{document}
```

The output is the same (well mostly indistinguishable).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I do not get why I was getting that error message. Now my code also works.

Comment: @DanielHernández Don't use `\tt` under any circumstance; either `\texttt{<text>}` or `\ttfamily <text>` inside a group.

Comment: Why do not use `\tt`? Any reference to related problems?

Comment: @DanielHernández Try `\documentclass{memoir}\begin{document}\tt a\end{document}`. The two letter commands for changing fonts have been deprecated for 20 years.

Answer (score 3):

Please always post complete documents not fragments. `\{` produces a `{` It is hard to guess from your code fragments what output you want but if it is

[image]

Then you just need

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

$\underbrace{\texttt{\{c\}}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear enough. Also I do a mistake with my code. Now I do not get that error.