# Why \texttt and \verb giving errors when using with LaTeX commands inside their input

Tags: verbatim, syntax, typewriter

On latest version of MikTeX, following works:

```
\begin{align*}
\int sinxdx && \texttt{test line 1}\\
\int{sinx}dx && \texttt{test line 2}\\
\end{align*}
```

But the following gives error:

```
\begin{align*}
\int sinxdx && \texttt{\int sinxdx}\\
\int{sinx}dx && \texttt{\int{sinx}dx}\\
\end{align*}
```

The error:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 94--102
[2] [3]
Overfull \hbox (40.0189pt too wide) detected at line 168
\OML/cmm/m/it/10.95 a=c \OMS/cmsy/m/n/10.95
```

When using \verb, the following is also giving a similar error:

```
\begin{align*}
\int sinxdx && \verb|test line 1|\\
\int{sinx}dx && \verb|test line 2|\\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `\texttt{\int sinxdx}`? `\texttt` puts you in text-mode so `\int` will obviouly produce an error, since it needs math mode; besides, use `\sin x` and not `sin x`.

Comment: Try `\mathtt` instead of `\texttt`.  Also, use `\sin x` instead of `sinx`---however, doing so will place "sin" back in the default math font.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I need to show the math display on the left and the corresponding syntax on the right as shown in Steve's response.

Comment: Special case of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24574/250119 -- in this case align environment are "special" that they grab argument as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get verbatim content inside the `align*` environments, my `verbatimbox` package can help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}{\lineA}\int \sin x\,dx\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\lineB}\int{\sin x}\,dx\end{myverbbox}
\begin{align*}
\int \sin x\,dx && \lineA\\
\int{\sin x}\,dx && \lineB\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the other issue of `\texttt`, try `\mathtt` instead, which processes its argument in math mode.

---

**ADDENDUM**

The OP asks if this can be done without an additional package.  Perhaps this would suffice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\int \sin x\,dx && \texttt{\string\int~\string\sin~x\string\,dx}\\
\int{\sin x}\,dx && \texttt{\string\int\string{\string\sin~x\string}\string\,dx}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a work around to accomplish this without using extra packages. I'm using amsmath package. The \mathtt will not work since I would like to show the syntax in the text mode exactly as you are showing on the right in your image above.

Comment: @nam Please see ADDENDUM.

Comment: thanks. Your ADDENDUM works. I was just reading [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/181121/22810) when I received your response.

Comment: @nam I just revised my addendum to get the braces and backslash in a tt font.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `\verb` inside `align*`, just like in the argument to any other command; `align` is a special environment that reads its contents before starting typesetting and this has the consequence that `\verb` is not allowed. If you want to make examples of input and output, you can use `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}ll}
\int \sin x \, dx & \verb|\int \sin x \, dx| \\
\addlinespace
\int \cos x \, dx & \verb|\int \cos x \, dx|
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Please, note the correct TeX notation; the spaces are optional (except the one between `\sin` and `x`.

[image]