# Why does \texttt not work on braces?

Tags: fonts, braces, typewriter

Why does `\texttt` not work on `\textbraceleft` or `\{`? Is there any solution to solve this?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \texttt{\textbraceleft} \texttt{\{} \verb|{|
    \end{document}
```

Note: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/181118/140814) for more details.

Comment: use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Because of encoding?

Comment: The default OT1 encoding has various curious properties as it supports only 128 chars and should better be avoided. Load always T1 with pdflatex.

Comment: Check the font table in `texdoc encguide` -- actually not there's only table of cmr10 here not cmtt10 -- nevertheless cmtt10 font does have {}, but not cmr10.

Comment: The cause && explanation is pretty much identical to [characters - Underscores in words (text) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48632/underscores-in-words-text) .

Comment: Wait actually it's duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181118/how-to-escape-curly-braces-within-texttt?rq=1 (just notice it on the related question) but the answer there is a little worse...

Comment: @user202729 Well, I searched the key words before asking the question but didn't find it....

Comment: I didn't find it either, only notice it only related panel to the right -- anyway having more question for signpost might be useful.